# Is there something wrong with my nested for-loop? counting and incrementing values of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random, nested

So, I generate a 100 numbers between the range of 0 and 9. I store these 100 numbers in an array called 'array'. Then I have the array called 'count'. It has 10 elements, and I wanted to check the following: for each element in 'array' if it equals to 0-9 then count[0-9] increments by 1, count[0] = how many times number 0 appears and so on count[1] = 1, count[2] = 2... . I just keep getting the output of around 20k numbers and i suppose? the sum of each element?, no idea why. I was wondering if there is something major wrong with my for loop?

```
import java.util.*;

class RandomInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 100;
        int max = 10;
        int[] array = new int[size];
        int[] count = new int[max]; //count[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        int loop = 0;

        Random generator = new Random();


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = generator.nextInt(max); // Generates 100 random numbers between 0 and 9 and stores them in array[]
            System.out.print(array[i]);
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {// loop through 10 elements in count
                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){ //loop through 100 elements in array
                    if (array[x] == j) {// loop through each 100 elements of array[x] and if element array[x] = value
                        count[j] += 1; // then count[x] = x + 1
                        System.out.print(count[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("0 appears " + count[0] + " times.");
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.print(array[i]); this line was only to check if my array worked. And it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Login is Perfect only mistake which i found u made is with the brackets........!

Generate the numbers using first loop and then count the number of occurrence using different for loop.

Here is your code's modified version which generates 10 numbers and counts the individual number occurrence count.....

```
public class RandomInt {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 10;
    int max = 10;
    int[] array = new int[size];
    int[] count = new int[max]; //count[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    int loop = 0;

    Random generator = new Random();


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = generator.nextInt(max); // Generates 100 random numbers between 0 and 9 and stores them in array[]
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) 
    {// loop through 10 elements in count
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            { //loop through 100 elements in array
                if (array[x] == j) 
                {// loop through each 100 elements of array[x] and if element array[x] = value
                    count[j] += 1; // then count[x] = x + 1
                    //System.out.print(count[j]);
                }
            }

    }

    System.out.println("3 appears " + count[3] + " times.");
}
```

}

Comment: Huh, would ya look at that. Thank you! :) Should have seen that. But hey, I'm a beginner in java and i make mistakes :) Thank you for the help and I appreciate all the comments, they help me very much. :) *i nested 3 for loops when I should have had 2, and take 1 step at a time(each task at a time there).

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to do this without nested loops, so forgive me for suggesting this as a fix rather than finding the issue in the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
   int num = generator.nextInt(max);
   array[i] = num;
   count[num]++;
}
```

One loop, incrementing the count for each number as it appears. You may need to ensure all the entries in count start at 0, but even then an additional loop through 10 entries is MUCH faster.

Answer (score 1):

To increment your counter, you don't need to have two nested for loops. Instead, you can use the value of array[x] as your counter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    count[array[i]]++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've nested your counting loop inside of your random number generating loop. Move the counting part outside.

Edit: The reason you're getting like 20k or whatever instances of zero is because when you set `array[0]` with a random value, you also check how many instances of 0 are in `array[1]` to `array[99]`.

Comment: Upvoting because you found the actual problem with his method. I would still suggest replacing the approach, but this will in fact work.

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* shouldn't do your count until you have finished assigning your numbers, but here is how you *could*. Note that you want the value at `array[i]` to be your index to count.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  array[i] = generator.nextInt(max); // Generates random numbers
  count[array[i]]++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
```